# DomPDF - addInfo (base64_encode) and setEncryption

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, pdf-generation, dompdf

I am having an issue with DomPDF and base64_encode with setEncryption function.

This is a sample of my code.

```
    // Render the HTML as PDF
    $dompdf->render();

    //Encode title into base64 and add it to PDF Meta
    $title_64 = base64_encode( $title );
    $dompdf->getCanvas()->get_cpdf()->addInfo( 'Subject' , $title_64 );

    //Locking pdf to allow printing only
    $dompdf->getCanvas()->get_cpdf()->setEncryption( '' , '' , array( 'print' ) );

    // Output the generated PDF to Browser
    $dompdf->stream( $post->post_name . ".pdf" , array( "Attachment" => TRUE ) );
```

So pretty much what is happening once PDF is downloaded all meta data is missing.

As soon I remove `base64_encode` function that is wrapping `$title` Meta data is back.

Also if I keep `base64_encode` but I remove

`$dompdf->getCanvas()->get_cpdf()->setEncryption( '' , '' , array( 'print' ) );`

Everything seems to be working but I am able to modify PDF which I don't want.

As my end result I should be able only to print PDF which is what i have now + all Meta data to be

`base64_encoded`

Did anyone encounter similar issue ?

Comment: Why should the metadata be base-64 encoded at all? It doesn't make any sense...

Comment: This is a client request and it got to be done this way.

Comment: Can you share an example output "with" the "missing" data?

Comment: https://1fichier.com/?9oi8nccm76 <- a pdf file with missing meta data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the CPDF class/version, which is used by DomPDF. The encrypted strings are not escaped correctly:

```
/Producer (Œa6Sq©åðÇ9Å—ÙÒ°Çl¡ÿÝøVóVÑª!Õñ¶7(Þýä¡)
```

There's an open bracket near the end of the string, which is not escaped nor balanced.

The logic in [these lines](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/13181634fc1f0121f73ab5f8cd10648241ae0a0d/lib/Cpdf.php#L1419) is faulty. The strings are escaped prior encryption which is simply wrong.